# how to flip cards if match keep open if not flip back

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a memory game in which if two cards are the same they are a match and would stay open if not they'll flip back everything is working fine except that when there is no match the second card I click on will not open it will stay closed and the first card will flip back so it knows there is no match and does not open the second card from first place

am using javascript to manipulate the effect.

HTML:

I have two divs representing each side of a card

```
<div class="card-holder">
    <div class="closed-card"></div>
   <div class="opened-card"></div>
</div>
```

.
.
. code is repeated for each card

CSS:

```
.closed-card {

transition: 1s;

position:absolute;

transform: rotateY(0deg);

backface-visibility: hidden;

cursor: pointer;

}

.opened-card {

transition: 1s;

transform: rotateY(180deg);

backface-visibility: hidden;

position:absolute;

}
```

javaScript:

```
var a=document.querySelectorAll('.opened-card');

var b=document.querySelectorAll('.closed-card');

var count=0; //a variable that will track how many cards are opened
```

when a card is clicked the first face 'b' is rotated by 180 and added a class 'test'. The same thing to the second face 'a' rotates by 0 and added a class 'open'

a loop that adds an event listener which does a function to rotate a card when a card is clicked and test if there is a match

```
for (let x=0;x<16;x++)
{
b[x].addEventListener('click',function()
{
b[x].style.transform="rotateY(180deg)";

b[x].classList.add('test');

a[x].style.transform="rotateY(0deg)";

a[x].classList.add('open');
count++;

if (count===2)
  {
    test();
    count=0;
  }

}); }
```

when two cards are clicked there is a function to compare if there is a match it will keep them open if there is no match it will flip them back

```
function test()
{
  var v=document.querySelectorAll('.open');
  var d=document.querySelectorAll('.test');
  if (v[0].style.backgroundImage===v[1].style.backgroundImage)
  {
    console.log("yes");
    v[0].classList.remove('open');
    v[1].classList.remove('open');
    d[0].classList.remove('test');
    d[1].classList.remove('test');
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("no");
    d[0].style.transform="rotateY(0deg)";
    v[0].style.transform="rotateY(180deg)";
    d[1].style.transform="rotateY(0deg)";
    v[1].style.transform="rotateY(180deg)";
    v[0].classList.remove('open');
    v[1].classList.remove('open');
    d[0].classList.remove('test');
    d[1].classList.remove('test');
  }
}
```

without the conditions my cards would flip over nicely the problem is after adding the condition if there is a match or not. If there is a match the two cards will flip and remain open no problem with that, but when clicking two cards that happen to be not the same this is what happens: I click on the first card, it flips and stays and when clicking the second card it remains closed and won't turn at all instead the first one flips back and the message that no match will appear. If anyone could notice what might cause that I would be thankful.

I also tried to set a timeout for the test function but that wouldnt change anything

```
setTimeout(test(),2000);
```

Comment: Use a `setTimeout`. For instance, see how this programmer created a memory game here: https://github.com/ashleighc207/fend-memory-project/blob/db9dd8646ed6709b719013b5620ac4e81fff1b0c/js/index.js#L148. She is basically saying *"show the cards for 0.6 seconds, so the user can see them, then after that flip those cards"*.

Comment: I tried setting a time out on the test function when calling it setTimeout(test(),2000); but nothing changed i dont know if my format is wrong or the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I agree with the above. The syntax of your code is a little hard to follow, but it appears that there's nothing in the way of timing. If,in the same block of code, you tell a face down card to face up, and then face down again, it's going to appear as though nothing happened at all.

Comment: @Rose Show us how you tried to set a timer (not in the comment, edit your question).

Comment: @Rose Thanks for your edit. It should be `setTimeout(test,2000);`, no parentheses.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado worked finally!! I can't believe I was stuck just for this simple mistake thanks a lot. Do you have any idea how I could prevent the clicking of the next pair of cards until the previous ones flip back?

Comment: There are several different ways, like removing the listener before the `setTimeout` and adding it again at the end of `test`.